# Looking for online Swiss pairing software

Tags: software, swiss-pairing

I would appreciate if somebody could recommend a good Swiss pairing program. I'd prefer online version with multi-language option and free version but cheap one is also good.

I've found http://www.free-swiss.com/ but do you know other ones?

Comment: Check out https://ChessNut.Club we run Swiss and Quad tournaments and it's been great for our club. Also has some registration features and club management which have been helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My club uses [Swiss Manager](http://swiss-manager.at/). It is very good but not cheap. 150 euros for the full version, 75 euros for the light. It is perhaps worth looking at what it does to get ideas if you are thinking of writing your own.

One I downloaded some time ago but still haven't got round to playing (so I can't give any recommendation) is [OSwiss](http://sourceforge.net/projects/oswiss/) which is a project on Sourceforge.

Comment: thank you, @Brian Towers, I'm not planning to write a new. One of my friends is looking for a good pairing software (mainly in Hungarian) and only if I can't find one then maybe, alternatively, I'll help with creating one in Hungarian

Comment: @harcos Swiss Manager is available in Hungarian amongst a lot of languages. The light version supports up to 60 players and 11 rounds. Maybe that would be good enough for your friend? The one criticism I've heard of SM is that manual pairings (2 players are going to be late for the 1st round so you want to pair them against each other for example) are difficult. You can do them but it is not straightforward. You have to read the manual ;-)

Answer (score 7):

You could try this free service: https://swisssystem.org/

It’s simple and easy to use. It works fine on mobile devices. The maximum player count is 200.

Comment: This is the best free online option AFAIK.

Answer (score 5):

[SWIPS](https://swips.eu/) is also online tool for managing tournaments. It includes much more than just a swiss system and round robin, but you can use it solely for that purpose if you want.

Right now its free, available languages are English and Slovak.

Answer (score 4):

An offline alternative is [Vegachess](http://www.vegachess.com), which it is also homologated by FIDE. AFAIK Vegachess just uses javafo as its pairing engine. Linux version of vegachess is free to use and Windows version not very expensive.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for an easy-to-use, FIDE-approved online platform, take a look at [ChessManager](https://www.chessmanager.com/en/solutions/software).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As offline alternative, there is my program VinczeSwiss: http://vincze.euweb.cz or http://vinczeswiss.sweb.cz