# Looking for online Swiss pairing software for reporting USCF tournaments

Tags: uscf

We organize a monthly USCF tournament. We would like to know if an online Swiss pairing software for USCF tournaments exists.

In the following Chess Stack question ([Looking for online Swiss pairing software](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8608/looking-for-online-swiss-pairing-software)), we found very good information. However, it seems that none of the online websites mentioned in that question help to report the results to USCF. What do you know about it? Are you a USCF tournament director who uses any of these websites?

We are looking for a software that automates or simplifies the reporting of results to the USCF. At this time, we are doing it manually using the USCF website.

If what I am looking does not exist, I would like to know what are the best options. We are willing to pay if that helps. At this time, we have found that [Chess Manager](https://www.chessmanager.com/en/solutions/software#faq) has a free version for 20 players or less, and it costs 49 dollars per year for the full version.

Comment: Why not ask the USCF? Ask if they have an api where you can send your results automatically. Chess manager at 49usd per year is probably reasonable, ask them if they can support USCF automatic results submission. I plan to develop a swiss system tour manager, I am searching for a program that can do swiss pairing and use it as part of a swiss tour manager. If not I will have to develop first the swiss pairing program. Do you have a link or guide how to submit manually your results to USCF? Perhaps it can be automated.

Comment: Here in Belgium, there is a pairing software made available by the national chess organization (KBSB-FRBE) called Swar (former was called PairTwo). You could download it from their website for free. I suppose there should be a similar software available by the USCF. Either your club or the USCF should be aware of this (you're not the only one organizing tournaments ;-) ).

Comment: @ITM Fantastic! Can you give a formal answer with the link to the website that you are mentioning? Is it available in English?

Comment: @Beginner: https://www.frbe-kbsb.be/sites/manager/PRG/SWAR/SwarSetup_v6.10.exe is the latest version today, you can check it under https://www.frbe-kbsb.be/sites/manager/GestionSWAR/SwarResults.php as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChessManager here!
Just wanted to let you know we just released a new version with USCF Reports:

- Set Country/Federation to "United States"
- Enable "Local Rated Tournament" Toggle
- Fill "Data for Local Federation" Form
- Download by clicking "Local Registry Report"

[image]